# How to get a id from a url using SQL QUERY. The ID changes dynamically. the database is Sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have url like:

```
http://mysites.xyz.com/_layouts/ng/ActivityStream.aspx/id/2624D92223261D370D7287C9E83CAEEA/Activity%20Stream%20Post.
```

I need to get the 2624D92223261D370D7287C9E83CAEEA. But not able to do so. my current query is

```
 SUBSTRING(@URL2,LEN('http://mysites.xyz.com/_layouts/ng/ActivityStream.aspx/id/'),LEN(@URL2)-LEN('http://mysites.xyz.com/_layouts/ng/ActivityStream.aspx/id/')- CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(@URL2))))
```

Please suggest.

Comment: What SQL type are you using? (Which database) eg. PSQL (PostgreSQL), MySQL, T-SQL (MS SQL Server), etc.

Comment: You could do it easily using any server side language like php or ruby and then pass the result to your SQL query.

Comment: Is it always `/id/<some alpha-numerics>/Activity/`..., or can it change?

Comment: By just going through the functions, I guessed its SQL Server!

Comment: yes zohar, the structure is always the same but the length of <some alpha-numerics> keeps on changing.

Comment: Also, welcome to stackoverflow. in future questions, please use the relevant tags to inform people what is the database you are using, what is your code language, and other things like that. For more information, please read [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
       @URL2, 
       CHARINDEX('/id/', @URL2)+4, 
       CHARINDEX('/', @URL2, CHARINDEX('/id/', @URL2)+5)
        - (CHARINDEX('/id/', @URL2)+4))
```

**Note:** This assumes that the id is always followed by at least one more slash.

**Breakdown:**
The first argument of the substring is the string that contains the full expression.
The second one is the first index after `/id/`.
The third one is the desired length - calculated by the first index of `/` after `/id/` - the first index after `/id/`.

### update

To cope with strings that does not contain a slash after the id value, use case:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
       @URL, 
       CHARINDEX('/id/', @URL)+4, 
       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/', @URL, CHARINDEX('/id/', @URL)+5) > 0 THEN
       CHARINDEX('/', @URL, CHARINDEX('/id/', @URL)+5)
        - (CHARINDEX('/id/', @URL)+4)
       ELSE
          LEN(@URL)
       END
       )
```

Comment: You get this error when a the url does not contain a slash after the id value. This is why I've asked you this question in the first place. I'll edit my question in a few minutes to cope with this new information.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is always the same then you can try:

```
SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(@s, LEN(@s) - 58), '/Activity%20Stream%20Post', '')
```

or:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@s,'/Activity%20Stream%20Post', ''), 'http://mysites.xyz.com/_layouts/ng/ActivityStream.aspx/id/', '')
```